# Would it be useful to provide feedback sooner for some questions?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, user-interface

I'm looking at the question [How to set up apache2 alias links on ubuntu 13.04 for a rails 4 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364997/how-to-set-up-apache2-alias-links-on-ubuntu-13-04-for-a-rails-4-app):

[image]

Notice the question received a close vote, but there's no feedback provided to the user. Some close votes, like *Close as Duplicate*, provide feedback immediately.

Providing feedback as early as possible would likely improve the user experience. The person who asked the question could improve a question before it is closed; and the folks who read and answer questions could get an improved question.

Would it be useful to provide feedback sooner for some questions?

**Note**: this is not an on-topic/off-topic discussion. For [ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssl) and [openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openssl) tags, the consensus is configuration questions are on-topic under the "tools used by developers" clause from the site's policies.