# Can I view the reason my question was close-voted for?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, close-reasons

My recent question got a close vote and link at the bottom now says `close (1)`, but I can't find anywhere why the person who voted for closing made his decision, so I can probably improve my question.

Is there any way I can see the reason or is it a privilege gained with more reputation?

Comment: I think the privilege to see it is 3k rep.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, the bottom section [this help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) mentinos the ''closed'' and ''reopened'' review queues that become available at 3000 rep, but nothing about viewing close reason of own questions.

Comment: Click on `close` like you wanted to close yourself. Don't vote, but you can see how others voted. Unfortunately, the moment you yourself voted is the moment you can no longer trace sub-reasons this way (the duplicate / specific off-topic reason).

Comment: I find it slightly ironic that *this* question has received a close vote.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As long as you have at least 250 rep and it is your question (the [see close-votes privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes)), you can always take a look.

Click `close`, and you will see how others voted.

If you yourself already voted, you can garner less info this way, but at least you'll get an overview of the top-level reasons.

Of course, if you have 3000 rep and thus the [Cast close- and re-open votes privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), the requirement of it being your question is dropped.

Comment: if the question is closed, I (12.6K) don't see "close" link, where can we see closed by who and when?

Answer (score 43):

So uh, I just did some science to figure this out:

[image: trolllollollollol]

And yeah, you can't, not until you have 250 rep. I *thought* you could see the reasons even without the privilege by clicking the link (and remember it being that way, at least I think I do), but that's obviously not the case.

It's very .. odd .. that you can't. I would support showing this in a slider under the question, just above the comments *provided that there are two or more votes, and a consensus*. If the reason folks are choosing are anything other than blatantly off-topic, it's *actionable* information, and you should probably see it.

I'm going to look into it more.

Comment: The blatantly off topic is only available for flaggers rather than voters. It was deemed a bad idea to allow flaggers to write custom messages. So, you'll never see the blatantly off topic, unless someone writes it in a custom message as a close vote, in which case it's a comment.

Comment: IIRC, this information is hidden to very low-rep users because it was thought it would be confusing and perhaps disheartening - you suddenly see "close(1)" appear, and there's no indication of what that means or what you can do about it; someone, somewhere, thinks you did something wrong. OT and Dup votes generate comments that are probably a lot more helpful here; we talked about expanding this to *other* close reasons, but couldn't really come up with good guidance there ("this question *might* be unclear... or maybe not... but you might want to edit it to clarify it...")

Comment: I think you should *always* be notified of the reasons for close votes on your own question.  I don't think you should wait until there is 2 and a consensus.

Comment: Well, so why _did_ the singleton cross the road?

Comment: `[php]` lol, icwatudidthar.

Comment: Related: [Would it be useful to provide feedback sooner for some questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269125/would-it-be-useful-to-provide-feedback-sooner-for-some-questions)

Comment: Not letting the user see even the _first_ close vote and its reason is utterly counter-productive. When I vote to close a 1-rep user's question it's because I'm trying to _tell_ that user something ("you need to ask this question better, and here's how"). The user can fix this and I'll cancel my close vote. Now it turns out that it all happens behind the user's back? I thought this was supposed to be _educational_. How can secrecy educate?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Because the entire highway system resides in the singleton, and therefore it technically crosses every road.

Comment: @TimPost well, there _is_ only one entire highway system so a singleton is a solid abstraction for it, obviously.

Comment: And note, I'm not talking about showing them `close (3)` - more along the lines of 'Uh, something might be wrong here ...'

Comment: If the close reason is actionable, would it be reasonable to extend the automatic duplicate comments to some (or all) of the other close vote reasons? Like we do with the VLQ review queue?

Comment: @matt This is very likely why when you down vote something it prompts you with "Consider adding a comment if you think this question could be improved." Is there something similar for the flagging system telling users to please add a comment, or no?

Comment: Why do I keep wanting to click the "upvote" on the screenshot?  ;)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: To get to the same side.